# Paginate entries when I do not have a criteria model?

Tags: pagination, entrymodel, plugin-supersort

I have to...

- merge results from multiple different criteria models
- use Supersort to order my entries in the desired sort order
- [...]

...and need to paginate them for my index page. As the [`paginate`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/paginate) tag doesn't work with arrays of element models, is there any other solution to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in no means an elegant solution, and can almost certainly be improved. But it did its job just fine.

```
{% set veterinarians = craft.entries({
    section: 'veterinarians',
    order: 'premiumVet desc, postDate desc',
}) %}

{# more filter/search params #}

{% set entriesPerPage = 20 %}
{% set page = craft.request.getParam('page') %}
{% set page = page ?: 1 %}
{% set offsetParam = (page - 1) * entriesPerPage %}

{% set veterinarians = veterinarians.offset(offsetParam).limit(entriesPerPage) %}

{% set isNextPage = veterinarians.offset(page * entriesPerPage).limit(1)|length %}
{% set queryString = craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath()|replace('/page=\\d+&?/') %}
{% set queryString = queryString ? '&' ~ queryString %}
{% set nextUrl = isNextPage ? craft.request.url ~ '?page=' ~ (page + 1) ~ queryString %}

{% for entry in veterinarians %}
    {# loop entries #}
{% endfor %}

{% if nextUrl %}
    <div class="js-pagination-trigger">
        <a href="{{ nextUrl }}">Weitere anzeigen</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Just a follow up to this now I look at it in more detail - it's a tad harder when combining two element types because you can't just use the offset + limit approach as easily on the queries -> because you need to do the bracketing on the sorted array.  But other than that it seems like it will be much the same.

Comment: Yes right, I totally didn't notice that my code doesn't work for arrays of element models. I hope you find a working solution using Twigs slice filter (bracketing), but you could get into troubles with performance using such an approach rather soon. Not sure if there is a way to work with element IDs first, but it's probably tough to get this sorted with your different types. A custom plugin solution would be fastest, as you could query for a subset of your (mixed) elements for each pagination page.

Comment: Yes, the plugin seems the best way as if someone does a really broad search, hundreds or more entries could come back with the full query.  But honestly in our case I think very few would look beyond top 50 search results, so I am simply going to use some limits for now and get some feedback before solving a problem that might not even exist I think.  The purist in my wants to solve it, but the 'get this thing done' part of me is currently winning.....for now ;)

Comment: Hi carlcs, this is a great solution. Can you update your answer for Craft 3 please?