# Combined entries from sections across locales

Tags: entries, localization, pagination

I'm merging entries from two separate sections across locales.
All going well but when I try to paginate the results I get the following error:

```
Recoverable error

Argument 1 passed to Craft\TemplateHelper::paginateCriteria() must be an instance of Craft\ElementCriteriaModel, array given,
```

The offending code as follows (simplified):

```
{% set pages = [] %}
{% set devNews = craft.entries.section('newsDevelopment').status(null).find() %}
{% set alumniNews = craft.entries.section('newsAlumni').status(null).locale('prior_alum').search('shareNewsAlumni:1').localeEnabled(false).find() %}
{% set pages = pages|merge(alumniNews) %}

{% paginate news as pages %}
    {% for article in news %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

As I say, works fine/as expected without the paginate but as soon as I try to paginate I get the error.

Any thoughts on above appreciated.

Comment: `{% paginate news as entries %}` is a typo an you meant `pages`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The `paginate` tag requires a criteria model, which means you have to come up with your own pagination solution.

See an example here:
[Paginate entries when I do not have a criteria model?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12455/paginate-entries-when-i-do-not-have-a-criteria-model)